# how to align "justified" a string in drawing.graphic.drawstring method

Tags: c#-4.0

How do I align "justified" a string in `drawing.graphic.drawstring` method in a `printpage` event in c#?

There is `stringalignment.far`, `stringalignment.center` but nothing like `stringalignment.justify`. How do I do it for for multi line text?

Comment: Justification requires a hyphenation engine to produce acceptable results.  None is built into the .NET Framework.  This is the kind of job to pass to a word processor.

Comment: What to do now to solve this problem